# What command just check for existence of an xpath in an html file but not print anything?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xmllint

```
$ xmllint --xpath '//b' --html - <<< '<html><body><div>abc</div></html>'
XPath set is empty
```

xmllint still print something. I just want to check the exit status to know whether there is a match to the xpath. Is there a command line program that can do so?

Answer (score 1):

As `--noout` and `--nowarning` options would not suppress `"XPath set is empty"`
 , use the trick with redirecting all output to `/dev/null`:

```
$ echo '<html><body><div>abc</div></html>' | xmllint --xpath '//b' --html - &> /dev/null
$ echo $?
10
```

Comment: I only need the exit status. When the input is very large, `xmllint` still checks the whole input even if it has seen a match to the xpath early in the input?

Comment: @user1424739, I've posted a working solution for your initial condition. You may try making up another nuances but that would be another questions